# Fast HP Regeneration

Tags: borderlands-2

On some YouTube videos I have seen, the player regenerates health very fast when they become hurt. However, I don't know how to regenerate so fast.

Is there any particular skill or ability that allows you to regenerate HP very fast?

**FACT:** All videos I have seen that kind of regeneration play gunzerker.

Comment: That's some fearsome regen!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He's a [Gunzerker](http://www.omfgnetwork.com/salvador/), and their brawl tree have health regen abilities, being a "tank" class. 
Especially, from that link:

> Level 22-31 – Alternate assigning points into Ain’t Got Time to Bleed (first) and Last Longer. Health regeneration and longer Gunzerking is what you’re all about when tanking for the team.

and

> Level 37-41 – Max out  Sexual Tyrannosaurus (really?) that gives you health regeneration while taking damage. In other words you will be in god mode for real.

Also, there is a legendary shield that regenerates life (source: [Borderlands 2 wiki](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Shield))

> **Neogenator**,     Anshin,     Legendary: Regenerates health when active. Damage to shield increases health regen rate.

Comment: and the skill tree doesn't? :P

Comment: I play Soldier and Mechromancer, so the sheild is something I'd love to track down.

Answer (score 4):

Gunzerker has a couple regen skills when taking damage and when gunzerking I think. Mechromancer regens health when their mag is full with a skill and the Siren tree has one which regens more health the less heath you currently have and another which regens health for you/your party when Phaselock is active.

In addition to various skills, there's various class mods and shields that help you regen health. The NEogenator is the only health regen shield I know of, there's also the Blood of Terramorphous relic with ~.5% health per second regen. Assorted class mods also have health regen as a main effect, but these tend to be absolute values not relative to your total health, and furthermore they seem to universally be extremely underpowered, especially at high levels.

IIRC there's also a Seraph (pink) relic which regens health, but it's ridiculously tedious to acquire (as all seraph weapons are) so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

In this video he sudddenly regenerates a huge amount or health in about a second. This is because whenever a gunzerker uses his action skill (Gunzerking) he instantly regenerates nearly all of his health. After that the regen is still very good, but nothing like that first second.  That sudden short burst of just crazy regen is gunzerker specific.

If you are looking to make another class regen like a gunzerker; good luck.  You can make any class regen some but the amount of regen on other classes will typically be less.

The soldier has some minor regen skills like able (regen a small % of hp per sec for 3 seconds after damaging anb enemy), and Preparation (more total shield capacity + same regen as able but only as long as your shields are full), and a class mod that adds max health and a number of health regen per second (Note:  this number is the direct hp per second, NOT a percentage of total hp).

Zero has an ability where he has hp regen while using his action skill, another skill (i think it's called resurgance) where you get some percentage of your total hp (4% i think but cannot swear to it) restored for killing an enemy, and a class mod with simmilar hp regen to the soldier one.

The siren has a phaselock related regen (elated i think it's called), a team hp regen class mod, the Sustenance skill (0.4% of your total hp per sec per lv max at 2% before class mod bonus'), the Life Tap kill skill (nice nod of the head to Everquest there), and the hp orbs from the Sweet Release skill (also linked to phaselock) can help quite a bit too.

The mechromancer has the skill Cooking Up Trouble that when maxed gives 2% health regen when clip is full, and Discord in the red tree that also adds 3% hp regen, so that'll get ya to 5%, and the With Claws skill also restores some hp. That said; regen is meaningless if you build the Mechromancer a certain way. Skip to 23 minutes in and watch the result of this guys build:

Bottom line, no one regens like a Gunzerker regens; HOWEVER, just because they regen crazy fast does not mean they are better than other classes.  I personally hate playing a gunzerker.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of Zero's class mods also allow your character to regenerate health (I believe they are 'Bloody', or 'Survivor' Class Mods), though probably never as quickly as the Gunzerker, as the sniper isn't built for tanking